# simple normal crossing divisors on Fano manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fano-varieties

Let $M$ be a Fano manifold. And $D=\mathop\sum\limits_{i=1}^r\tau_iD_i\in|-\lambda K_M|$ is a simple normal crossing $\mathbb{R}$-divisor where $\tau_i\in(0,1)$. Can we know that $D_i$s are ample (or $c_1(D_i)\geq 0$ for $i=1,\cdots,r$)? If not, for $D\in |-\lambda K_M|$, can we find such a decomposition of $D$ so that the condition "$c_1(D_i)\geq 0$ for $i=1,\cdots,r$" satisfies?

What if $M$ is a toric Fano manifold and $D_i$ are toric divisors corresponding to the faces of the moment polytope?

Comment: What do you mean by "$c_1(D_i)\geq 0$"?

Comment: It means that the line bundle with respect to $D_i$ admits a Hermitian metric such that its curvature is semi-positive.

Comment: Or you can understand that $D_i$ is nef.

Comment: OK, I thought you might mean that....

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=M_1\times M_2$ and $D_i$ the pull back of an anti-canonical divisor on $M_i$. Then $D_1+D_2\in |-K_M|$ but they are individually not ample. (They are nef though).

I don't know what you $\lambda$ is, but if you want coefficients strictly between $0$ and $1$, then choose two different anti-canonical divisor on each factor and multiply them by $1/2$.

To get an example with not nef components take $M$ to be the blow-up of $\mathbb P^n$ in a single point with $E\simeq \mathbb P^{n-1}$ the exceptional divisor. Then $M$ is a $\mathbb P^1$-bundle on $\mathbb P^{n-1}$. (There is a projection $\pi:M\to E$ with fibers isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$).

Then the anti-canonical divisor of $M$ is something nef pulled-back from the $\mathbb P^{n-1}$ plus a multiple of $E$ which is not nef. More precisely, one can write $K_M\sim a\pi^*H+bE$ where $H\subseteq E$ is the hyperplane class. Now, if $F\simeq \mathbb P^1$ is a fiber of $\pi$, then $K_M|_{F}\sim K_{\mathbb P^1}$ so $b=-2$ and 
$(K_M+E)|_E\sim K_E\sim -nH$ and $E|_E\sim -H$, so $a=-(n+1)$, that is, 
$$
-K_M \sim (n+1)\pi^*H +2 E.
$$

You can also consider the blow-up morphism $\sigma: M\to \mathbb P^n$ and write 
$$
-K_M \sim \sigma^*(-K_{\mathbb P^n}) - (n-1) E
$$
in which case $-(n-1)E$ is not nef, but then the coefficients are not in the range you declared.

Comment: I add a comment. And can we get that $D_i$ are nef?

Comment: Right, that's the obvious next question, but I think you can't get that either. Let me add more love to this answer.

Comment: If you take $M$ the blow up uf the projective plane at 3 points, there is an anticanonical divisor whose components are six  $-1$-curves.

Comment: Rita, that's a nice example! I guess on some level it is the same as mine, but more elegant!

Comment: Kovacs, thanks for your answer. But I am still confusing. The coefficient of $E$ in the anti-canonical divisor of $M$(in your answer) is minus, i.e. $-K_M= -K_{\mathbb{P}^n}- a E$ where $a>0$ so it is still nef. Is there something wrong in my statement? And if, please forgive me. Thank you again.

Comment: @Daniel: If you write it that way, yes, but if you write it as something pulled back from $\mathbb P^{n-1}$ (not $n$!) then you have $K_M=(\ ) + (-2)E$. ....and $-E$ is not nef either...., but I thought you wanted something effective.

Comment: Taking products with a non rational Fano manifold you can probably get also examples where $M$ is not rational.

Comment: @Rita, you are right, of course.

Comment: @Kovacs, yes the divisor cared is the effective ones. And so if it does not hold for all Fano manifolds. Would you like to give me some examples such that the decomposition of effective nef divisors holds. The only example to me is $\mathbb{P}^n$, but it is too trivial, so would you like to provide me some other examples, in particular the toric Fano manifold. Thank you again!

Comment: @Kovacs, what I care now is an example of Fano (toric ) manifold, such that the simple normal crossing effective decomposition exist. I do not want it holds for all Fano manifold and all decompositions since the decomposition is not unique.

Comment: @Daniel, I'm not sure what you want. Since $-K_M$ is ample, allowing fractional coefficients you can always find a smooth effective very ample representative. Otherwise, if you have a more nuanced question, then you are better off asking a new question than asking in the comments.